# I want to place UIActivityIndicator on a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a scrollview on the view, I want to place `UIActivityIndicator` on a view while posting data to server.

I am adding my indicator by using the below line:

```
[scrollview addSubview:activityindicator];
```

but dont know it is not showing on a scrollview.

Please any one help me.

Comment: Could you please provide more code?

Answer (score 2):

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityindicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];

activityIndicator.center = scrollview.center;

[activityindicator startAnimating];

[scrollview  addSubview:activityindicator];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are posting your data to server with asynchronous or synchronous request.
If you using synchronous request you will not see your activityindicator working.

And yes dont forget to [activityindicator startAnimating];

Have fun.